# Page Information Using Wiki API

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I am using the wiki api in python to grab the categories and the sub-categories of various wikipedia pages. The trouble I am running into is that I receive more information when pulling the sub-categories of a category page (specifically the pageId for each sub-category) but when I pull the categories for that same category page I only get the page title and not the pageId.

This is what I get when I run a request for the page "Category:Class-base programming languages" and here is the url I am using:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&format=jsonfm&titles=Category:Class-based_programming_languages

```
"pages": {
        "909420": {
            "pageid": 909420,
            "ns": 14,
            "title": "Category:Class-based programming languages",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "ns": 14,
                    "title": "Category:Object-oriented programming languages"
                }
```

This is what I get when I run a request for that same page, but finding the sub-categories. This is the url I am using: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonfm&list=categorymembers&cmnamespace=14&cmlimit=100&cmtitle=Category:Class-based_programming_languages

```
"query": {
    "categorymembers": [
        {
            "pageid": 3623580,
            "ns": 14,
            "title": "Category:C++"
        },
        {
            "pageid": 44668068,
            "ns": 14,
            "title": "Category:Java (programming language)"
        },
        {
            "pageid": 44667679,
            "ns": 14,
            "title": "Category:Ruby (programming language)"
        }
```

I would like to retrieve the pageId when I search for the categories as well. Am I missing a parameter in the url?

Comment: I doubt it's possible. It probably uses the [categorylinks table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table) for that query, and that does not store page IDs.